# Can we use ItemAnimator to do animation on view's focus change

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android TV app, there I am currently I am doing animation on `RecyclerView` when the focus on a view changes in the `onBindViewHolder` of the `adapter` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    holder.row.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                startEnterAnimation(view);
            } else {
                startExitAnimation(view);
            }
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

But this morning I was watching [RecyclerView ins and outs - Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqBlYJTfLP4&t=1724s) talk and found that, it is a bad approach to do RecyclerView animations in `onBindViewHolder` method. Instead `ItemAnimator` should be used.

Although I found some documentation to do animation while *adding*, *removing* and *moving* items in a RecyclerView, but there was no reference to do animation on view's focus change.

***So, is there any way to do animation on focus change using ItemAnimator. Or the approach I am using is the best we have for now?***